# Angular 7 ngx-intl-tel-input onBlur() event any solution?

Tags: angular, angular7, onblur

I stucked with a issue in Angular 7 with ngx-intl-tel-input package.
i just want to check phonenumber on blur.

```
   <ngx-intl-tel-input [cssClass]="'form-control'" [preferredCountries]="preferredCountries"
        [enableAutoCountrySelect]="false" [enablePlaceholder]="true" [searchCountryFlag]="true"
        [searchCountryField]="[SearchCountryField.Iso2, SearchCountryField.Name]" [selectFirstCountry]="false"
        [selectedCountryISO]="CountryISO.Canada" [maxLength]="15" [tooltipField]="TooltipLabel.Name"
        [phoneValidation]="true" name="PhoneNumber" [(ngModel)]="formModel.PhoneNumber" #PhoneNumber="ngModel">
      </ngx-intl-tel-input>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular Forms API has updateOn option you can use that to trigger ngModelChange on blur

**component.html**

```
    <ngx-intl-tel-input [cssClass]="'form-control'" [preferredCountries]="preferredCountries"
            [enableAutoCountrySelect]="false" [enablePlaceholder]="true" [searchCountryFlag]="true"
            (ngModelChange)="ngModelChange($event)"
            [searchCountryField]="[SearchCountryField.Iso2, SearchCountryField.Name]" [selectFirstCountry]="false"
            [selectedCountryISO]="CountryISO.Canada" [maxLength]="15" [tooltipField]="TooltipLabel.Name"
            [ngModelOptions]="{updateOn: 'blur'}"
            [phoneValidation]="true" name="PhoneNumber" [(ngModel)]="formModel.PhoneNumber" #PhoneNumber="ngModel">
     </ngx-intl-tel-input>
```

**component.ts**

```
 onChange(event){
    console.log(event);
  }
```

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-intl-tel-input-demo-wk4xxe)